Wifi adapter not supported in Asus Vivobook
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Vivobook. All working fine except for the wifi. It says wifi adapter not found. Unfortunately Vivobook doesn't have ethernet port either. This affects my office work. Can anyone please help me with this.

Does this answer your question? No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS
